# How to override the arguement of a particular task in airflow DAG

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG which contains two tasks.The Dag has been created like below:

```
default_args = {
    'catchup': False,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 1, 30),
    'retries': '2',
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=3),
    'queue': us_constants.CELERY_QUEUE
}


 with DAG(dag.dag_id+'.'+task_id, default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=dag.schedule_interval) as temp_dag:
    
   t0 = DummyOperator(task_id='t0')
   
   t1 = DummyOperator(task_id='t1')
```

Now I want to overide the value of retries from 2 to 3 for t1 in the same DAG which contains default arguements of retries as 2

How can I do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do:

```
t1 = DummyOperator(task_id='t1', retries=3)
```

parameters passed on operator level take precedence over values set in `default_args`.

Comment: @ElidKalif what if we want to override the value of custom operator in airflow and we have used apply_defaults.Because as far as I know apply defaults will take all the default parameters

Comment: apply_defaults is just a way to set parameters for operators in centralized way.